# If statement for UITextField's text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, if-statement, uitextfield

I have an app that asks you  a question (how many sides does this shape have) then I declare a uitextfield and call it txt, if u write 8 in the uitextfield and press done, you should go to the next question cause 8 was correct, here is my if statement code:

```
if (txt.text == @"8") {
    [self q7done];
} else {
    Fail *fail = [[Fail alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"Fail" bundle:nil];
    fail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:fail animated:YES];
     }
```

Okay! When I type in 8, it goes to the fail page. Sucks right, i dunno why??? I even tried  setting the text of the uitextfield to a label of a 0.02 alpha and changed the if statement to if the LABELS text is 8 then blah blah blah, help pls.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ([txt.text isEqualToString:@"8"]) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string1 = yourtextfield.text;
NSString *string2= @"8";
if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2]) { //compare here.
    [self q7done];
} else {
    Fail *fail = [[Fail alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"Fail" bundle:nil];
    fail.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:fail animated:YES];
}
```